# Internet Explorer Issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm learning HTML & CSS and have built a page: http://customstudio.co.uk/development

The page is working well apart from in IE (7 in particular). For some reason the body text is not displaying (see screengrab below).

Any ideas will be gratefully received.

Thanks in advance,

Tom Perkins

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<div class="breadcrumb">` is not closed, hence the `<div class="content">` sits inside `breadcrumb-wide`.

You have your e-mail address in plain text in your source code. You shouldn't do that unless you want to receive tons of spam on that address.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated! How can you avoid putting an email address in plain text in the source code?

Comment: @ Tom: You can use an image, or scrambled text that is unscrambled by javascript on page load. That will defeat most email harversters.